# SQL Server LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Here is my code

```
SELECT ID, Name, Phone 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.ID = 12 AND Table2.IsDefault = 1
```

The problem happens when Table2 is null, so, the query returns nothing.

How do I leave the last part of the query `AND Table2.IsDefault = 1` optional?

I've tried to short circuit the query using `OR` but I've found out that it works different than C#

Comment: If you want it `optional` then what is your expected output?

Comment: But... what if the table2 record DOES have one or more entries... is it possible?  If so, could there be multiple "IsDefault" values?  You might want to just move this IsDefault=1 to the LEFT-JOIN part of the query.

Comment: Nop, that is not possible. Table2 will always return 1 entry.

Comment: Which table is optional, table1 or table2?  Including a constraint on your optional table in the where clause results in the outer join being treated as an inner join.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Phone 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND Table2.IsDefault = 1
WHERE Table1.ID = 12
```

Comment: This is definitely the best approach.  Joel's answer will certainly work, but you'd have to futz with it every time you want a different value for table2.isdefault.

Comment: Also, this will be faster, since OR/COALESCE/ISNULL are not good for matching to indexes. I wrote the COALESCE() approach because at first glance the OP had already rejected moving the join condition in the comments, but reading it again, I think the OP's reasoning is in error there, and this should yield the same results. Since the OP accepted my answer, I edited it to include this suggestion, so that others reading this will be lead in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

```
 AND COALESCE(Table2.IsDefault,1) = 1
```

Reading the comments, it looks like your best solution is actually to move the condition to the join:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Phone 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND Table2.IsDefault = 1
WHERE Table1.ID = 12
```

Because it's an OUTER join, you'll still keep any Table1 information if the match fails, and given the statement that "Table2 will always return 1 entry" you're not risking filtering additional join results by moving the condition. You will get the **same** results as placing the condition in the WHERE clause.

The reason to move the conidtion to the ON clause is that the `COALESCE()`, `ISNULL()`, and `OR` all cause problems for indexes. With the condition in the ON clause, we don't need any of those, and so should end up with a better execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT ID, Name, Phone 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.ID = 12 AND isnull(Table2.IsDefault,1) = 1
```

You were almost there :-)

Comment: `IFNULL()` is for MySQL, `ISNULL()` for MS SQL/MS Access -- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: So what ? this is tagged SQLSERVER so I provided the correct syntax. Thanks for the link anyway, but W3Schools is certainly not a reliable source.

Comment: To clarify... I meant my comment to be informational, not corrective :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Phone FROM Table1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
  WHERE Table1.ID = 12 
    AND (Table2.IsDefault IS NULL OR Table2.IsDefault = 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to filter the results of Table 2 before they're joined with Table 1:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Phone 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE IsDefault = 1) AS Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.ID = 12
```