# Return Records ordered by count of records in a joint table in Symfony and DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have an issue with a DQL query, i have and entity Bar and Tip (it countain user comments on bars).

the issue is, i want to show a list of 6 bars ordered like so :

1. Top Bars first (the field status in the Bar entity)
2. Number of tips

my issue is that bars with no tips are not shown even if they are on Top bars.

here is my DQL Query.

```
$qb = $this->createQuerybuilder($this->getAlias());

        $qb
            ->select($this->getAlias().", COUNT(tp) AS HIDDEN nbTips")
            ->leftjoin($this->getAlias().'.tips', 'tp')
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq($this->getAlias().'.onTop', $qb->expr()->literal(true)))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq($this->getAlias().'.status', $qb->expr()->literal(Bar::BAR_STATUS_ENABLED_VALUE)))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('tp.status', $qb->expr()->literal(1)))
            ->groupBy($this->getAlias())
            ->orderBy($this->getAlias().'.onTop', 'DESC')
            ->addOrderBy('nbTips', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(6)
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Any help please ?

Comment: You can only use `where` once. Use `andWhere` after that.

Comment: yes the second where was commented i removed comments when i pasted it here, the issue is not from that where unfortunatly, thank you for the remarque.

Comment: Try moving the andWhere tp.status to the join like `->leftjoin($this->getAlias().'.tips', 'tp', 'WITH', 'tp.status', $qb->expr()->literal(1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue is a duplicate of this one : [SQL Server LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636436/sql-server-left-join-and-where-clause)

Bar with no tips are not shown because in your query tips must have a status of 1.

You should do a query like this (the important part is the leftjoin):

```
    $qb = $this->createQuerybuilder($this->getAlias());    
    $qb
        ->select($this->getAlias().", COUNT(tp) AS HIDDEN nbTips")
        ->leftjoin($this->getAlias().'.tips', 'tp', 'WITH', 'tp.status ='. $qb->expr()->literal(1))
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq($this->getAlias().'.onTop', $qb->expr()->literal(true)))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq($this->getAlias().'.status', $qb->expr()->literal(Bar::BAR_STATUS_ENABLED_VALUE)))
        ->groupBy($this->getAlias())
        ->orderBy($this->getAlias().'.onTop', 'DESC')
        ->addOrderBy('nbTips', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(6)
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```